# Java simple server error

Tags: java, html, sockets, text

Few hours ago I have started to learn java socket comunication. Now I'm trying to make server application whitch should return me data to webbrowser. 
My code:

```
try{
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(80);
    Socket response = socket.accept();
    String lol = "<html>hi</html>";
    OutputStream str = response.getOutputStream();
    str.write(lol.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
    str.flush();
    response.close();
    System.out.println("LOL works!");
    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

I have no error in server application, the message "LOL works!!!" prints in console but in webbrowser I'm getting this error:

[image: My error.]

Does anobody know how to repair it and get the text "hi" in webbrowser? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I've tried add it to telnet. This is the result:
[image: Telnet result]

Comment: You are listening on port 80, but connecting via HTTPS which defaults to port 443. That is one problem, for sure?

Comment: i'm working on 80. This is first image what i found on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just send out raw data to the browser and expect it to handle it - you have to follow the HTTP (protocol) which is described in [RFC1945](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt).

Specifically, you have to send out a few headers followed by a new line first as described in Section 4.1 of RFC1945.

```
try{
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(80);
    Socket response = socket.accept();
    String lol = "<html>hi</html>";
    writer = new PrintStream(response.getOutputStream());
    writer.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    writer.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    writer.println();
    writer.println(lol);
    writer.flush();
    response.close();
    System.out.println("LOL works!");
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that I've also wrapped your OutputStream in a PrintStream, since this is a lot easier than handling the OutputStream manually.

Comment: Using `\n` as a line break won't work there. The HTTP protocol specifies that `\r\n` has to be used. Don't forget the ones after the response body has been written.

Comment: Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Connection has been reseted

Comment: Even with `http` instead of `https`?

Comment: What? I'm using `http`. Ifyou mean that image, it's from google. I'm running everything on `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: So noone knows in what can it be?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from not sending a proper response, as Kristian Antonsen has pointed out, the problem is likely that you don't actually wait for and read the request before you respond. Arguably, that should not be a problem because of buffering, but even then it is likely that your server is simply "too fast", sending the response and closing the socket before Chrome has a chance to send the request, therefore triggering the "connection reset" problem that it reports.

Try implementing a server that is just a little more complete. Here's a simple example:

```
public void readRequest(Socket client) throws IOException {
    Reader raw = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "US-ASCII");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(raw);
    while(true) {
        String line = reader.readLine().trim();
        if(line.equals(""))
            break;
    }
}

public void writeResponse(Socket client) throws IOException {
    String lol = "<html>hi</html>";
    PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
    writer.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    writer.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    writer.println();
    writer.println(lol);
    writer.flush();
}

public void serveClient(Socket client) throws IOException {
    try {
        readRequest(client);
        writeResponse(client);
        System.out.println("LOL works!");
    } finally {
        client.close()
    }
}

public void serve() {
    try{
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(80);
        while(true) {
            Socket client = socket.accept();
            serveClient(client);
        }
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(Note that I haven't tried the code or anything, so there's no guarantee that it compiles as is.)

Comment: Works! Dunno why your answer hasn't marked as a solution. Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 0):

A web browser communicates with a web server using the [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP). Your server has to respond to a request from the browser according to this protocol if you want the browser to display the page correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with Chrome. Maybe [this one?](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42058)

Try fiddling with IPv6 settings.